# Want to create a list of view items in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a list of clickable items as :

```
val clickableViews: List<View> = listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text, box_four_text, box_five_text, constraint_layout)
```

where `box_xxx_text` parameters are view-ids of different items. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to add predefined elements, it's more convenient to use an array instead of a list.

```
val array = arrayOf(
            "One", "Two", "Three")
```

The first step to create a ListView is of course defining a ListView in your xml layout file.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This should do.
The second step is to define an array adapter to insert your array into your listview.

```
val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
```

Then you can create a variable for the listview, and add your array into it

```
    var mListView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_view)
    arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.layoutfilename, array)
    mListView.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

Job done, hope it helps!

Comment: Array is not more convenient than a List. Arrays do not have useful `equals` functions and they are mutable, which should be avoided when possible. Arrays should only be used when you need a mutable collection with a fixed size, or in code that needs to be extremely optimized at the expense of clarity.

Comment: ListView is also mostly deprecated

Comment: In this case he only needs it to start filling the list, (or at least that's I've interpreted), so Arrays are the most common and easily way to achieve the result he needs. Also thank you for sharing your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying view binding, I'd say that's the most efficient way...

This solution and a couple more variants are described here:

https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-color-my-views/issues/11

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31502896)

Answer (score 0):

you have to import in your build.gradle(app) the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin

steps:

1. on: build.gradle(app):

```
plugins{
  ...
  id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

2. sync project with gradle file
3. on your activity file (eg: MainActivity), you can now import use the library

```
import kotlin.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*;
```

Comment: [Kotlin synthetics for views are deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html)